# Odoo 9 Error creating an invoice from a Sales Order

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

After confirming a Sales Order, I try to create an invoice and Odoo gives me this error:

```
Configuration error!
Could not find any account to create the invoice, are you sure you have a chart of account installed?
```

The steps that I follow were the following:

1. Install Sales.
2. Install Accounting.
3. Configuring Chart of accounts according to Generic Template.
4. Create, and confirm a Sales Order.
5. Try to create an invoice from the Sales Order.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can u create another database and try again

Answer (score 2):

**Create New DB**

Install

1. **Sale**
2. **Accounting and Finance**
3. **Multi Language Chart of Accounts**

Then after checking it with latest odoo9 it's working on my end.